# How to get the name of each day in next month?

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
dt = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);
int x = DateTime.DaysInMonth(dt.Year, dt.Month);
MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());  // works ok - 31
```

And how can I say the following:

```
foreach (day in dt.Days)
{
string abc = dt.DayOfWeek.ToString();
MessageBox.Show(abc)
}
```

Problem is in the first line - foreach...

Comment: Well whatz wrong with the code you have ( you need to put in the brace brackets in case you want to execute both the code lines for the loop)

Comment: I added now the brackets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the job.

```
DateTime Base = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1).Month, 1);
int x = DateTime.DaysInMonth(Base.Year, Base.Month);
while (Base.Day != x)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Base.DayOfWeek.ToString());
    Base = Base.AddDays(1);
}
```

Comment: I would like to point out the LINQ answer by the other Alex is also perfectly valid (and in my mind far more elegant) but I am unsure as to any performance differences between the two.

Answer (score 4):

You can also leverage `Enumerable.Range` and LINQ (and the `DaysOfWeek` enum)

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);

Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(dt.Year, dt.Month))
    .Select(dayNumber => new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dayNumber))
    .Select(dayName => dayName.DayOfWeek.ToString()).ToList()
    .ForEach(day => MessageBox.Show(day));
```

The two `.Select()`s can be merged but I kept them separated for readability.

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
dt = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);
DateTime conditionDateTime = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month,DateTime.DaysInMonth(dt.Year, dt.Month));

 for (DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, 1); dt1 <conditionDateTime; dt1 = dt1.AddDays(1))
     {
        Console.Write(dt1.ToShortDateString() + " : ");
        Console.WriteLine(dt1.DayOfWeek);
     }
```

This will give you

```
8/1/2012 : Wednesday
8/2/2012 : Thursday
8/3/2012 : Friday
8/4/2012 : Saturday
8/5/2012 : Sunday
8/6/2012 : Monday
8/7/2012 : Tuesday
8/8/2012 : Wednesday
8/9/2012 : Thursday
8/10/2012 : Friday
8/11/2012 : Saturday
8/12/2012 : Sunday
8/13/2012 : Monday
8/14/2012 : Tuesday
8/15/2012 : Wednesday
8/16/2012 : Thursday
8/17/2012 : Friday
......
```

Comment: Am I not correct in thinking the code in the for loop's condition is run at every iteration of the loop and as such you create a new DateTime every loop? Also why create two DateTimes dt and dt1?

Comment: @Alex, you are right, in condition part of the loop, it is doing it for every iteration, that can be avoided by defining a condition date before the loop, I just wanted to give an idea, but I would edit the post to show the optimization

Comment: @Alex, dt was created to show the current date and dt1 to show the date for the next month, again just for an idea

Answer (score 1):

Try `DateTime.ToString(format)` method.

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
String dayName=dt.ToString("ddd");
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
string day = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddd");
```