# How to create an array from day names?

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the name of each day in next month?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288893/how-to-get-the-name-of-each-day-in-next-month)

I need to create an array from DayNames in currentMonth

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
dt = DateTime.Now;
string[] days = ( names of days);  // this month should be: Sunday, Monday...
```

How can I do this, pls

Comment: Take a look at your previous thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288893/how-to-get-the-name-of-each-day-in-next-month [alex's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11288983/142822)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Your last thread

```
DateTime Base = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1).Month, 1);
List<String> Days = new List<String>();
int x = DateTime.DaysInMonth(Base.Year, Base.Month);
while (Base.Day != x)
{
    Days.Add(Base.DayOfWeek.ToString());
    Base = Base.AddDays(1);
}
```

Then use

```
String[] StringArray = Days.ToArray();
```

If you need and array of strings and not a list.

Unless you really need an array I would just keep the list as it is, it can be used the same way so I cant see a good reason to needlessly do an array copy.

Or you can just do (as Habib.OSU suggested):

```
DateTime Base = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1).Month, 1);

int x = DateTime.DaysInMonth(Base.Year, Base.Month);
String[] StringArray = new String[x];
while (Base.Day != x)
{
    daysOfMonth[Base.Day - 1] = Base.DayOfWeek.ToString();
    Base = Base.AddDays(1);
}
```

This is most likely the quicker of the two.

Answer (score 3):

The LINQ way to get all day-names of the current month, starting with *"Sunday"*(f.e. in en-us):

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
String[] thisMonthDays = 
     Enumerable.Range(1, culture.Calendar.GetDaysInMonth(now.Year, now.Month))
               .Select(day => new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, day))
               .Select(date => culture.DateTimeFormat.GetDayName(date.DayOfWeek))
               .ToArray();
```

(since i'm from germany, the list starts with *"Sonntag"* here)

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can look for DayOfWeek enum http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek.aspx

```
var arr = Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
DateTime end_DateTime = 
        new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(dt.Year, dt.Month));

List<string> result = new List<string>();

for (DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, 1); 
     dt1 <= end_DateTime; dt1 = dt1.AddDays(1))
{
    result.Add(dt1.DayOfWeek.ToString());
}
```

In the end

```
string[] resultarr = result.ToArray();
```

This will give you

```
"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday" .... and so on for current month of July.
```

because `01/07/2012 (dd/MM/yyyy)` was Sunday and so on.

Answer (score 2):

```
    DateTime Base = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1).Month, 1);

    int x = DateTime.DaysInMonth(Base.Year, Base.Month);
    string[] daysOfMonth = new string[x];
    int i = 0;
    while (Base.Day != x)
    {
        daysOfMonth[i++] = Base.DayOfWeek.ToString();
        Base = Base.AddDays(1);
    }
```

From your previous question: [How to get the name of each day in next month?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288893/how-to-get-the-name-of-each-day-in-next-month)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do like this

```
  DateTime dt = new DateTime();
            dt = DateTime.Now;
            string[] days1 = { "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday" };  // this month should be: Sunday, Monday...
```

Hope this will help you :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(year, month,...); // initialize to first day in month
List<string> days = new List<string>();
do 
{
   days.Add(dt.ToString("dddd"));
   dt.AddDays(1);
} while (dt.Month == month);
```

Answer (score 0):

Days of week are always the same you don't need to tie them with current month.

If you are only concerned with being them in English.

```
string[] weekdays = { "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Saturday" };
```

If you want a list of all the days in a month see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022993/how-to-get-a-list-of-week-days-in-a-month).

Comment: @ Usman but, next month, first day will not be Sunday

Comment: It wasn't quite clear in the question, in that case see the link.

Comment: @Alice Not sure what are you trying to achieve, maybe you can highlight on the problem area

Comment: @ V4 I need the names of days in an array. This month will be Sunday, Monday... but next Month first day could be Wednesday...